# Apex:composition within a VF email template doesn't work

Tags: visualforce, email, visualforce-component, email-template

We're trying to use apex:composition in a Visualforce email template. This works fine if I simply do this:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Template Example" recipientType="Contact">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <apex:composition template="EmailTemplate">
            <apex:define name="body">
                This is the example body
            </apex:define>
        </apex:composition>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

But if I start to use any Visualforce merge tag or Visualforce component, then Salesforce won't compile the email template.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Template Example" recipientType="Contact">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <apex:composition template="EmailTemplate">
            <apex:define name="body">
                Hi {!recipient.FirstName}
            </apex:define>
        </apex:composition>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Salesforce will return 'Error: An unexpected error has occurred' when I try to save the email template. Is this known behaviour? What can I do to avoid it?

Comment: I've ran into this issue as well, were you ever able to find a resolution?

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be no real solution. Composition is simply not available in email templates when using merge tags or components.

Comment: :( We should probably post an idea, I think it makes a lot of sense to have composition as a great alternative to letter heads

Comment: If you create it, I'll vote on it :-)